# Extract all URL from entire WebSite

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-crawler

I want to crawl a website using C# or VB.NET. I'd like the crawler to extract the URL from the webpage and I'd also like the crawler to follow URLs so I am able to extract all the URLs from the website.

How can I write this?

Comment: Here are a few examples. [Web Crawler 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Crawler.aspx) [Web Crawler 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8fecf702-04d9-4ee8-854e-0a31b3c01176)

Comment: Link doesn't work for me...

Comment: I did this for a class in C++, it wasn't too difficult to implement.  If you like, all my code is open source.

Comment: every url on webpage but for entire site

Comment: what a webcrawler does is crawl through each link on each page, you can normally set how deep to crawl, and if to crawl other sites.

Answer (score 1):

What is a website in this case?

A local virtual directory?
A static web page?
Dynamic pages hosted somewhere?

Look at

```
wget --mirror
```

Curl could have options here, too.

Also, please read up about [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org) before you start scraping the net :)